# Android DialogFragment TextView setText() doesn't work

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

this is my onCreate() function:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //inflate the view
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_loading, null);     
    TextView loadingMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_loading_message_textview);
    loadingMessage.setText("test");
    //the dialog
    Dialog dialog;
    //set the dialog views
    int themeId = getDialogThemeId();
    //if there is no theme
    if (themeId == -1)
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    else
        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(),getDialogThemeId()); 
    //remove background
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    //remove title
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //set the content view
    dialog.setContentView(view);        
    //set cancel properties
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    return dialog;
}
```

this is the layout i'm inflating:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <!-- spinner -->

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" />

    <!-- text -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_loading_message_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" 
        android:text="LOADING"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

although i'm calling loadingMessage.setText("test") the loading message is keeping showing me "LOADING" in the message... any idea???

Answer (score 3):

ok i found the problem.
in the same DialogFragment I've implemented onCreateDialog and onCreateView as well.

This causes my view to be inflated twice. since onCreateView is called after onCreateDIalog, the view I've loaded in the onCreateDialog was overridden..

hope it will someone else